# How to place a marker and open standard google infowindow using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I was looking around for a solution, but I couldn't simply find it. The problem is that I want to use JavaScript Google Maps API v3 to place a marker on map using geocoding service. The only info I have is the address so I need to fetch place's position, so I have a string like that:

103 Olympic Boulavard, Parramatta, Sydney, NSW 2059

I have database full of addresses which need to be showed on map exactly in the same way.

What I could so far achive is showed here:

[image]

But I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

This is standard google maps bubble with address info. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  You have to code it to appear that way though.

The Google Maps API v3 provides directions and the places library will let you search nearby.  Not sure what you want to do for the rest.

Comment: Probably you want me to build html to insert inside comment box... well it's not the answer I want to get, but if it's the only solution I'll accept it.

Comment: That is the only way to do it on your own map (at least currently).  You can either link to a map on maps.google.com, with that infowindow, or build your own version using the services provided in the google maps API v3.